# Azure Data Factory Rest API pagination issue

Tags: azure, jira, azure-data-factory, jira-rest-api

I am new to Azure Data Factory and i am trying to copy data from JIRA to Azure Storage using Data Factory.
I am trying the JIRA REST API to fetch the data, but unfortunately i am struggling with pagination. Can Someone help me how to use the pagination in this case.

Request URL:
https://jira.abc.com/rest/api/3/search?jql=&startAt=0&maxResult=10

Sample response from JIRA:

```
{
    "startAt" : 0,
    "maxResults" : 10,
    "total": 200,
    "isLast": false,
    "values": [
        { /* result 0 */ },
        { /* result 1 */ },
        { /* result 2 */ }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the Copy Data activity (the block) in your pipeline
2. Click on
   the Source tab
3. Scroll down to Pagination rules and click the plus
   sign to add a rule
4. As highlighted below, put `AbsoluteURL` in the first box
   and then, for JIRA it appears (according to their docs) that you need to put `$._links.next` instead of `$.next_page` in my screenshot.  (This is the reference to the part of the JSON doc returned by JIRA containing the URL of the next page.)

[image]

Please comment if it works for you.

Refs:

[MS data factory docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#pagination-support)

[JIRA API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/pagination-in-the-rest-api/)

Comment: Hi Jason, 
Thank you for the reply. 

JIRA API docs you are referring is actually Confluence API  doc. Here is the correct doc URL https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/ .

In JIRA response, there wont be any next page and previous page URL. It only sends ```StartAt``` and ```maxResults```. We need to somehow use these 2 value to loop.

Comment: Ah OK my bad.  So it's nasty - there's no support for this pagination ... you can vote for the feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/40594570-support-for-dynamic-content-with-pagination-rule-i).  Meanwhile set a startAt pipeline variable set to 0, then an Until activity that ends when there is no data read from the API.   Inside the Until you'll need to increment the startAt variable and use it in your API relative URL.  As you can't reference a variable within its own assignment you'll have to copy startAt to a temp variable so you can increment it.